# Is there a shortcut to add exceptions to a method signature in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I am using the Eclipse IDE for Java and I want to know if there is shortcut to add exceptions in a method signature. Like if I am writing a method and I used `bufferedreader.readline()`, is there a shortcut to add the declaration `throws IOException` instead of writing it myself .

Comment: What do you mean? you wan to generate some `new IOException("whatever")` or do you want eclipse to add `throws IOException` to your method signature?

Comment: no i mean in the signature of the method like int foo() throws IOException ;

Comment: Just using 'Edit > Quick Fix' (Ctrl+1 or Cmd+1) should show the 'add throws' as one of its suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

When you hover your mouse over the statement, you will get the below popup. You just have to click on the `Add throws declaration` link

[image: When you mouse over the offending statement]

You can also press `Ctrl+1` for a similar popup, when your keyboard cursor is on the statement line.